# Prevent grid resizing in Zurb Foundation

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

We built a responsive site in Foundation and outside of specific tablet media queries the client doesn't want the grid to resize automatically as the browser width decreases.

Is there any simple technique that could be applied after the fact to prevent grid columns from resizing?

Comment: I'm not sure it'll work but you can try changing [this](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/_variables.scss#L89) value in your zurb variables to 0px

Comment: Thanks! Definitely worth a shot. The site was made using the CSS version not SASS, but I'm going to backwards covert and try that. If it works I'll post a comment and then please submit that as the answer.

Comment: remove css related to the respective screen resolutions from foundation css

    @media only screen..{
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can make the grid fixed width by modifying the .row selector.
From foundation.css:

```
.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  max-width: 62.5em;
}
```

You want to change the max-width property to be fixed, so just remove the max-width and replace with width:

```
width: 62.5em
```

You'll also need to remove any styles in a media query.